# How to Convert .USDz formats to .OBJ or .ABC files?

Tags: swift, xcode, terminal, usdz, houdini

I have been trying to build a solution to converting from .USDZ to other [3D formats].
Using online options you may convert [3D formats] to .USDz using:
https://www.vectary.com/3d-modeling-how-to/how-to-create-usdz-file-for-ar-online/
or
https://www.vectary.com/3d-modeling-news/usdz-converter-create-usdz-files-for-free-online-with-vectary/

Using Houdini plugins was not successful I was only able to import not export .USDz.

This basic command line converts from OBJ files, Single-frame Alembic (ABC) files, USD file (either .usda or usd.c) to .USDz.

```
xcrun usdz_converter myFile.obj myFile.usdz
```

Will this command convert the other way.

I have also found that this command line will convert [.OBJ, .ABC] to .USDz but don't know if it will convert the other way:

```
usdcat --flatten -o myFIle.abc myFile.usd
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have macOS + Xcode you can open .usdz file in the default viewer and export it to .obj file.

With your `mydocument.usdz` file open, select `File -> Export` and then select `"Geometry Definition File Format"`

[image]

Comment: Exporting as .obj from Xcode method doesn't export the textures and normals.

Comment: @MarcusAdams no surprises there... the `.obj` format technically only knows about vertices and surfaces. All the rest of the information is not stored there — at least, not in a standard, universally recognised way.